# Derivation of wavelength in a waveguide

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, maxwell-equations, wavelength, waveguide

I'm trying to derive this expression for the wave length in a wave guide. I'm following this derivation from the Feynman lectures https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_24.html#Ch24-F4. I do not understand how he went from eqn 24.17 to eqn 24.19. Where did $\lambda_{g}$ and $\lambda_{0}$ come from?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the text
$$k_z=\frac{2\pi }{\lambda_g} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \lambda_0=\frac{2\pi c}{\omega}$$
Further
$$k_z=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\omega}{c}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\pi }{a}\right)^2}$$
From above (first line)
$$\frac{2\pi }{\lambda_g}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda_0}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\pi }{a}\right)^2}=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda_0}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\lambda_0}{2a}\right)^2}$$
Invert both  side
$$\lambda_g=\frac{\lambda_0}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{\lambda_0}{2a}\right)^2}}$$
As required!

Comment: i know not about this question. however considering u know about wave guides.... for maxwells equation in conductors why is the divergemce of E set to zero?